# How to write neither ___ nor ___ in First Order Logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

If X exists, it is neither Y nor Z.

Would this be written as X ⇒ ¬Y ∨ ¬Z  ?

Or would it be X ⇒ ¬(Y ∨ Z)  ?

Comment: Neither $a$ nor $b$ means not $a$ and not $b$

Comment: "Neither X nor Y" means that X is false and Y is false.

Comment: Your second option $\left(X \implies \not(Y \lor Z)\right)$ is equivalent to J Tanner and J Taylor's suggestions.

Comment: De Morgan's Law:  $\quad\lnot(Y\lor Z)\equiv\lnot Y\land \lnot Z$

Comment: $\neg Y\lor\neg Z$ means "either not $Y$ or not $Z$", which is not "neither $Y$ nor $Z$".

Answer (score -1):

\begin{equation}
(\exists x \in S)(\exists y, z \in S) \Rightarrow x \neq y \wedge x \neq z
\end{equation}

Where S is some arbitrary set